# Soil moisture using a capacitive sensor - can cheap version of it contaminate soil

Tags: arduino

Maybe a bit silly question but I was wondering if these cheap versions of soil moisture capacitive sensor (Corrosion Resistant Analog Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor) may release chemicals to soil.

Not sure if there is any FDA approved version of such a sensor.

Comment: I would suspect it would not cause any problems in the short term, but may begin to wear out with time

Answer (score 1):

The PCB is normally covered with a chemically resistant solder mask, so under normal conditions it would not release anything into the soil.

If the mask is damaged, then the resulting corrosion would release small amounts of copper and possibly tin (and lead if not RoHS compliant) however that portion of the board is not normally inserted into the soil (the probe would fail quickly in that situation).

If the soil destroys the mask you have much bigger problems than the probe materials (ie toxic organic solvents).

It's doubtful that the FDA would be the involved, as soil is not considered a food nor a drug (unless you have pica).  The EPA perhaps, but on a practical level they're more concerned with industrial waste situations.

Comment: I agree. As long as there's no exposed metal the soil should be fine. Though one also think about the solder mask material. It's usually some sort of cured epoxy. A quick web search revealed this list: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/chemical-resistance-epoxy-d_786.html. I'd look for compounds that can be found in soil (salts, acids and alkaline). From a brief look, this should be fine.